# Is a signed Amazon s3 url safe to share?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am using aws sdk, in Java, to generate signed object urls from a given bucket. These objects are images for which I want to generated a signed url using following code.

```
 URL url = amazonS3Client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);
```

Following is an example of generated url

[image]

In the urls there is AWS3AccessKeyId and signature that will be visible to end users and developers. Is there a chance for someone to generate PUT, DELTE, etc  operations on objects using the information in the url. Is it safe to provide these urls to users who I don't know ?

**Background**

I like to share images and other object urls with people, who will use them in their websites. For example,a url to display an image in a website, or url from where user can download a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they will not be able to use these URLs to do anything other than what you allow. So if you generate a pre-signed url to get a particular S3 object, they will ONLY be able to use it to get that S3 object. They can't reverse-engineer the url to give themselves access to other buckets or objects.